# Topology, continuous indicator function

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $A$ be a subset of $X$. Let $f(p)$ be a function from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that equals $1$ if $p$ is inside $A$ and $0$ otherwise.

I've seen that $f$ is continuous on $p$ iff $p$ isn't in $Cl(A) - INT(A)$.

I tried to prove that but not sure if I'm right.

Assume $f$ is continuous. Let $U$ be an open set around $p$. Let $V$ be a subset of $f(U)$. If $V$ is open then its source is also open. But any set that originates in the boundary of $A$ isn't open. And that shows $p$ isn't in $A$'s boundary. Correct?

The other direction is this: assume $p$ isn't in $A$'s boundary. Then it's in $A$'s interior and therefore in an open set. Or it's outside $A$'s closure and therefore it's inside a set that its complement is closed so it's open and that's why each set in $f(p)$ has an open source.

Comment: You are making confusion with symbols $x$ and $X$. Please clarify.

Comment: By the way, $f(x)$ is not a set, it is an element. So it does not make sense to take $V$ subset of $f(x)$.

Comment: I tried to clarify my question. thx

Comment: Ok. Your proof is still incorrect: there are lots of mistakes.

Comment: Great. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution. Write
$$X= (int A) \cup (X\setminus clA) \cup (clA \setminus intA)$$
this is a partition of $X$ (easy exercize). Let $p\in X$. There are three cases:

1. $p\in int A$. Then $f(p) = 1$ and . Let $V$ be a neighbourhood of $f(p)=1$. Now $intA$ is an open neighbourhood of $p$ and $$f(int A) = \{1 \} \subseteq \{ f(p)\} \subseteq V$$ so $f$ is continuous at $p$.
2. $p \in X\setminus clA$ same argument, $f$ is continuous at $p$.
3. $p \in clA \setminus intA$. We need to show that $f$ is NOT continuous at $p$. There are two cases:

3.1. $p \in A$. Then $f(p) = 1$. Since $p\notin intA$ every open neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ intersects $X \setminus A$. Hence $f(U) = \{0,1 \} $ which is not contained in $(0,2)$.

3.2 $p \notin A$. Then $f(p) = 0$. Since $p \in clA$ every open neighbourhood of $p$ intersects $A$, hence using a similar argument we conclude that $f$ is not continuous at $p$.

This concludes the proof.

Comment: 3.1 {0,1} not contained in (0,2). How that shows that f isn't continuous?

Comment: @CIsForCoocckies Use the definition of continuity at a point. You take a neighbourhood of $f(p)$ (I took $(0,2)$) and you need that locally  at $p$ all values should lie in that neighbourhood. But alas, you always have some point near $p$ which evaluates $0$, so you have no continuity.

Comment: Oh, the 2 threw me off. Thx